# How to select DataFrame columns when one column is separate from the others?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this DataFrame from which I want to grab column 5 along with other columns in a dynamic range.

```
        0       1    2    3    4        5    ...    235    236   237   238   239  240
0     ACSSF  2019e5  md  000  0001  0000001  ...  22288  15090  8357  3759  1378  459
1     ACSSF  2019e5  md  000  0001  0000002  ...  21922  14734  8189  3723  1378  447
2     ACSSF  2019e5  md  000  0001  0000003  ...    366    356   168    36     0   12
3     ACSSF  2019e5  md  000  0001  0000004  ...  22205  15042  8318  3751  1378  459
```

I can select columns in a dynamic range using `df.iloc`

```
start = 79
end = 83    
columns = df.iloc[:, start:end]
```

However I want to grab column 5 with the other columns. How can I achieve that? The result should look like

```
      5        79       80      81      82
0  0000001  6018848  2917613  186260  189641
1  0000002  5247469  2531081  166668  167130
2  0000003   771379   386532   19592   22511
3  0000004  5937028  2877671  184124  187244
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to concatenate indices and slice objects, for instance:

```
import numpy as np

start = 2
end = 4    
df.iloc[:, np.r_[0, start:end]] 

       0   2  3
0  ACSSF  md  0
1  ACSSF  md  0
2  ACSSF  md  0
3  ACSSF  md  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this: concatenating the two dataframe you need (column 5 and your dynamic range)

```
df2 = pd.concat([df['5'], df.iloc[:, start:end]], axis=1)
```